# Returning multiple dataframes with Python

Tags: python, dataframe

So I want to write a function that looks something like this:

```
def return_all_tables(parameter):
    a_table = a(parameter)
    b_table = b(parameter)
    c_table = c(parameter)
    ...
```

Here, `a`, `b` and `c` are all different functions returning the dataframes `a_table`, `b_table` and `c_table` respectively.

What I'm not sure now is how to write the return statement to make it return the content of every dataframe.

Comment: a return statement doesn't *display* anything. Do you mean "*return* the content of all the dataframes"?

Comment: Yes, my apologies.

Comment: **Edited** your question to reflect that (you could have done that yourself!). Anyway, what's wrong with `return (a_table, b_table, c_table)`?

Comment: It just returns a list saying (<DataFrame object>, <DataFrame object>, <DataFrame object>), but I want the function to display what's in these respective dataframes simultaneously.

Comment: that's exactly what I asked when you said you didn't want to display...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want something like this

```
def return_all_tables(parameter):
    a_table = a(parameter)
    b_table = b(parameter)
    c_table = c(parameter)
    return a_table, b_table, c_table

a, b, c = return_all_tables(parameter)
display(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

`return a_table, b_table, c_table` will return a 3-tuple containing the dataframes.